# .Net Core 2.0 API returning json with quotes around property name

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .Net Core application that I have just updated from 1.1 to 2.0.
The problem I am having is with the json that is being returned. The json contains a JavaScript Web Token (JWT).

I have controller endpoint that looks like this...

```
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("getToken")]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Post([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromBody] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
            var authTokenJson =  _authTokenService.GetTokenJson(_jwtOptions, applicationUser);
            return Ok(authTokenJson.Result);
    }
```

Under the 1.1 version the response from this endpoint looks like this when printed in the browser console...

[image]

After upgrading to 2.0 it now looks like this...

[image]

Note that the property names are now in quotes. This causes an issue for the front end AngularJS application that is trying to process the object.

Does anyone know why this happens and how it fix it?

Comment: *".Net Core 2.0 API returning json with quotes around property name"* Good! That's valid JSON then. Note that what you're looking at in your first screenshot isn't the JSON, it's a parsed object. Your second screenshot is probably JSON (in a string) but it's hard to tell from that. So that's what you need to find out: Why is it not being parsed anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your comments.

I have found that with the 1.1 format I was able to get away with doing this in the front end...

```
this.currentToken = <string>response.json().access_token;
```

but with the new format I now have to add a .parse call like this...

```
this.currentToken = <string> JSON.parse(response.json()).access_token;
```

It now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

asp.core .net 1.1

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody]GraphQLQuery query)
    {
       ...
        var json = _writer.Write(result);
        var rr = new ObjectResult(json) { StatusCode = (int)httpResult };
        return rr;
    }
```

asp.core .net 2.0

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody]GraphQLQuery query)
    {
       ...
        var json = _writer.Write(result);
        dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        var rr = new ObjectResult(obj) { StatusCode = (int)httpResult };
        return rr;
    }
```

Both of these functions returned the same result on their respective platforms.
The 1.1 version was probably interpreting the json string as json that had to be turned into a dynamic and in 2.0 it is just a string.